# Open file URLs in PDFNet / PDFTron WebViewer

Tags: javascript, pdftron, pdfnet

I'm trying to use PDFNet / PDFTron WebViewer within an Electron based application. The user should be able to select a file from the local filesystem to open. But when passing a file:// URL for `initialDoc` I always get the error `Error retrieving file: file:///Users/mat/Desktop/document-generator/xod/Anchoring/Anchoring.xod?_=-22,. Received return status 0.`.

Has anyone an Idea how this could be solved? Copying the file in a folder close to `index.html` and using a relative URL is not an option, since the PDF documents are quite big.

Answer (score 0):

The `initialDoc` property does not seem to support the `file://` URI scheme. However, you can open PDFs directly in the browser by using the HTML5's File API, and then using the (hidden?) `loadLocalFile` function:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
$(function() 
{
   var viewerElement = document.getElementById("viewer");
   window.myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
       documentId: "pdf",
       documentType: "pdf",
       path: "lib",
       type: "html5",
       initialDoc: "GettingStarted.pdf"
   }, viewerElement);
});

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
function handleFileSelect(e) 
{
  var files = e.target.files; // FileList object
  console.log("Loading file " + files[0].name);
  window.myWebViewer.getInstance().loadLocalFile(files[0], {});
}

</script>
```

Such a functionality is also demonstrated in the [WebViewer online demo](http://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/showcase/). Note that `documentId` and `documentType` must be set to `"pdf"` for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. But this only seems to work with the html5 viewer. When using the html5mobile viewer there is no method loadLocalFile and getInstance returns undefined. Is there maybe a way to also open XOD from the local file system and, more important, also in the html5mobile mode?